# ArrowInvalid: Column 4 named input_ids expected length 1000 but got length 328

Tags: python, machine-learning, language-model

```
# Formatting
block_size = 128  # or any number suitable to your context


def group_texts(examples):
    # Concatenate all 'input_ids'
    concatenated_examples = sum(examples["input_ids"], [])
    total_length = len(concatenated_examples)
    # Organize into sequences of fixed length
    sequences = [
        concatenated_examples[i : i + block_size]
        for i in range(0, total_length, block_size)
    ]
    result = {
        "input_ids": sequences,
        # Shift the labels for CLM
        "labels": [sequence[1:] + [tokenizer.eos_token_id] for sequence in sequences],
    }
    return result


tokenized_dataset = tokenized_dataset.map(
    group_texts,
    batched=True,
    batch_size=1000,  # or any number suitable to your context
```

I am not getting what the block_size and the batch_size refers to?

Answer (score 0):

Batch_size determines how many examples will be processed simultaneously in parallel. For example, in your code, as batch_size=1000, it means 1000 instances will be processed at the same time.

Block_size determines the fixed length of each sequence. The concatenated_examples list is divided into sequences of length block_size using a sliding window approach.

```
 Column 4 named input_ids expected length 1000 but got length 328
```

You may need to promise instances number divisible by 1000, as you only have 328 instances, you may use a little batch_size like 8.

Answer (score 0):

set

```
tokenized_dataset = tokenized_dataset.map(
    group_texts,
    batched=True,
    batch_size=8)
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**