# Hugging Face Datasets map with batch=True gives ArrowInvalid error for mismatch in a column's expected length

Tags: python, huggingface-datasets

I am tokenizing my dataset with a customized `tokenize_function` to tokenize 2 different texts and then append them together, this is the code:

```py
# Load the datasets
data_files = {
    "train": "train_pair.csv",
    "test": "test_pair.csv",
    "val": "val_pair.csv"
}
datasets = load_dataset('csv', data_files=data_files)

# tokenize the dataset
def tokenize_function(batch):
    # Get the maximum length from the model configuration
    max_length = 512

    # Tokenize each text separately and truncate to half the maximum length
    tokenized_text1 = tokenizer(batch['text1'], truncation=True, max_length=int(max_length/2), add_special_tokens=True)
    tokenized_text2 = tokenizer(batch['text2'], truncation=True, max_length=int(max_length/2), add_special_tokens=True)

    # Merge the results
    tokenized_inputs = {
        'input_ids': tokenized_text1['input_ids'] + tokenized_text2['input_ids'][1:],  # exclude the [CLS] token from the second sequence
        'attention_mask': tokenized_text1['attention_mask'] + tokenized_text2['attention_mask'][1:]
    }
    return tokenized_inputs

# Tokenize the datasets
tokenized_datasets = datasets.map(tokenize_function, batched=True)
```

This code is generating this error:

```
ArrowInvalid: Column 3 named input_ids expected length 1000 but got length 1999
```

The error is misleading, it suggests that the `input_ids` length is 1999, while it is impossible for the maximum length of this column to be more than `512`. If I set `batch=False` there is no error.
I also tried with different batch sizes such as 8 or 25 (cause the number of samples is divisible by 25) but it did not work.
I read similar questions [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76509562/arrowinvalid-column-4-named-input-ids-expected-length-1000-but-got-length-328), but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

when the "batched" argument is set to true in dataset.map function, the "batch_size" is by default set as 1000. In your last step since you are adding the tokenized_texts it might be possible the vectors are getting concatenated instead of adding up and thus giving a 1999(excluding the cls token).